# How to find max in Ruby without using "max" function

Tags: arrays, ruby, function, max

I need to find the max value of an array without using the `max` method. Right now I have:

```
def max(arr)
  largest_num = arr(1)
  arr.each do |num|
    if element >= largest_num
      largest_num = num
    else
      largest_num = largest_num
    end
    puts largest_num
  end

  my_numbers = [20, 30, 40, 50]
  puts max(my_numbers)
end
```

Comment: i was told i should use .sort and .last but not quite sure where to even start

Comment: I'd recommend reading "[mcve]". You also need to work through at least the first couple chapters of any Ruby tutorial.

Comment: THANK YOU EVERYONE FOR ANSWERING!

Comment: It's one thing if you must use `sort` and `last`, another if that was just a hint or suggestion. As @shelvacu noted, sorting is an efficient way of just finding the maximum (or minimum). The approach you have taken is fine, just a few tweaks are needed which I'll mention in a separate comment.

Comment: Firstly, it's almost never a good idea to have a `puts` in a method that computes the thing that is to be `puts`.  If you instead have the method `max` simply return the maximum value, you can then write `puts max(arr)` you have the `max` available for use elsewhere in your program where you need the value for some other calculation. Secondly, you don't need `else largest_num = largest_num`, which accomplishes nothing. A nice way of writing the `if/else/end` is the single line `largest_num = num if element >= largest_num`.

Comment: Assuming you are not required to use `sort` and `last`, I suggest you give an answer yourself that has your code cleaned up. You want a very short method `max` followed by `puts max(arr)`. You may think it strange to give an answer to your own question, but it's done all the time.

Comment: In my penultimate comment above, make that `largest_num = num if element > largest_num`.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just use `sort` and `last`?

```
array = [3,7,2,4,6,1,8,5]
array.sort.last
#=> 8
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are required to use `sort` and `last`, then the answer below will not work for you.

`arr.sort.last` is inefficient, since it requires sorting the whole array when all you need is the biggest. Try something like:

```
arr.reduce{|largest, num| if num > largest then num else largest end}
```

---

The `reduce` function (also aliased as `inject`) is used to "reduce" an array down to a single object. To implement a sum, you could do something like:

```
num_arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
num_arr.reduce(0){|sum, num| sum + num} #=> 15
```

`0` is the starting value of the sum, and then for each element the block is run with the sum so far and the element in the array. Then the result of the block (`sum + num` is returned since in ruby the last statement is implicitly returned) is set as the new value of `sum` for the next element. The final value of `sum` is what is returned.

This is similar to doing:

```
sum = 0
sum = sum + num_arr[0]
sum = sum + num_arr[1]
sum = sum + num_arr[2]
sum = sum + num_arr[3]
sum = sum + num_arr[4]
```

If you don't specify a starting value, then the first element is taken as the starting value. So, in my `reduce` solution, the first element is set as the "largest", and then for each element in turn the largest is either passed on or if the element is bigger than the current largest, it becomes the new largest.

Comment: Using `sort` and `last` are the requirements.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Fair enough, I have added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> i was told i should use .sort and .last but not quite sure where to even start

It's really important to be a self-starter when programming. It's an essential characteristic, because the field and all technologies are moving quickly. I'd suggest reading "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421)" also, especially if you want to use Stack Overflow as a resource.

Here's how to learn to experiment with Ruby and to teach yourself:

Ruby has [IRB](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/irb.html) bundled with it. Type `irb` at the command-line and it should open and present you with a prompt. At that prompt you can enter Ruby expressions and see the result. My prompt is probably not the same as yours because mine is customized, but you can figure out how to work with that:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0>
```

To assign an array to a variable:

```
irb(main):001:0> my_numbers = [20, 30, 40, 50]
=> [20, 30, 40, 50]
```

I can look at the value assigned to `my_numbers` by entering the name of the variable and pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
irb(main):002:0> my_numbers
=> [20, 30, 40, 50]
```

I can experiment using methods on `my_numbers`:

```
irb(main):003:0> my_numbers.shuffle
=> [50, 30, 40, 20]
```

That took the array and randomized it. It didn't change `my_numbers`, it only shuffled the array and output a new array in the shuffled order:

```
irb(main):004:0> my_numbers
=> [20, 30, 40, 50]
```

Each time `shuffle` is run it randomizes the array and returns another array:

```
irb(main):005:0> my_numbers.shuffle
=> [50, 20, 30, 40]
irb(main):006:0> my_numbers.shuffle
=> [40, 20, 30, 50]
```

Since you want to use `sort` and `last` to find the maximum value, it'd be good to start with an out-of-order array. Testing `sort`:

```
irb(main):009:0> my_numbers.shuffle.sort
=> [20, 30, 40, 50]
```

The array is sorted after shuffling.

Here's what `last` does:

```
irb(main):010:0> my_numbers.last
=> 50
```

Now you know enough to figure it out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you were really told that you should use `sort` and `last` then the answer is quite simple:

```
2.1.1 :003 > [2,3,1,4,8,6].sort.last
=> 8
```

If you want it in method:

```
def max(arr); arr.sort.last; end

2.1.1 :004 > def max(arr); arr.sort.last; end
=> :max 
2.1.1 :005 > max([2,1,3])
=> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

First sort the array without using the sort method if you are trying to solve this without the default function

```
asc = [45,34,12,4,5,32,54,76]
asc.each do |a|
    i = 0
    asc.each do |b|
        if b > asc[i +1]
            asc[i], asc[i + 1] = asc[i + 1], asc[i]
        end
        i += 1 if i < asc.size - 2
    end
end
p asc.last
```

This will give the largest number from the sorted array